# How to install Samsung Xpress M2070FW on Ubuntu 20.04 | Samsung M2070 Series

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, printer, samsung, ppd

The latest Samsung driver from the vendor page

General:
https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377

Details of the driver:
https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377/swItemId/fp-191129-2

`uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz`

does not list any appropriate driver ppd file under cups (http://localhost:631/admin) or in the ubuntu "Select Printer Driver" menu:

[image]

When printing I get error messages like, when using the wrong driver:

```
SPL ERROR - Please use the proper driver.
     POSITION : 0x0 (0)
     SYSTEM : h6fwsim/xl_op
     LINE : 206
     VERSION : SPL 5.73 06-16-2013
     ERROR CODE : 11-1113
```

or

```
%!
  userdict dup(\004)cvn{}put (\004\004)cvn{}put
                                               /cups_handleerror {
                                                                    $error /ne
```

Which ppd file should or could I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this driver to work through trial and error.

Choose the `scx3200.ppd` file or in the  "Select Printer Driver" menu choose

1. Settings
2. Printers
   [image]
3. Add Button
4. Await detection of M2070 (Model Generic Text-Only Printer)
5. Click the settings wheel ([image])
6. Printer Details
7. Select from Database...
8. Await "Loading drivers database..."
9. Select "Samsung"
10. Select "Samsung SCX 3200, 2.0.0"
11. Select the "Select" button

[image]

Comment: Did scanning works for you with this driver?

Comment: Scanning via USB with `simple-scan` works, if I scan with colors on 300 dpi. When scanning with 150 dpi it fails sometimes to scan the whole page and has some kind of interruption in the forward movement of the scanner.

Comment: Thanks, gonna test it again as most probably I need to restart system and then try as I need to do it after reinstalling `uld` drivers or sometimes when updating packages which are restarting `udev`.